# pipController.isPictureInPicturePossible false on initial play

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have most of my custom PIP-enabled video view working in SwiftUI, but when I first launch the app, play the video and try to start PIP, `pipController.isPictureInPicturePossible` returns false. I even tried force starting it by calling `pipController.startPictureInPicture()`, but `failedToStartPictureInPictureWithError` doesn't get called.

But when I just open the app and the video is paused, I can start PIP, and the PIPed video starts in the paused state.

Force starting PIP did not work.